# Two VS Code instances with different settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When streaming, I want one VS Code instance with a very big font size for viewers on smaller screens.  I'd also like a VS Code instance off-stage that doesn't need to be so big for notes and research.  Can two VS Code instances have different settings for the same logged-in user?

Comment: install the Insiders version, they have separate locations to store global settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, global user settings are a singleton, but you could override them in per-workspace settings. Per-workspace overrides global.

So if VSCode1 is doing WS1, and VSCode2 is doing WS2, they could have different settings.

https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getstarted/settings/

IS this what are you looking for?

Comment: This is perfect. Inside `.vscode` create `settings.json` that includes `{ "editor.fontSize": 10 }` and now this VS Code is 10 pt while all others are the other size.